# How to pass different hidden input fields based on the clicked submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have two hidden input fields with the same name but with different `id`. I want to pass it via an action based on different submit button. When I click on the 'normal' process button it should pass the `#normalfee` hidden field value, and when clicking on 'urgent' it should pass `#urgentfee` value.

```
<form name="home" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="fee" id="normalfee" value="49">
  <input type="hidden" name="fee" id="urgentfee" value="99">
  <input type="submit" name="Normal Process">
  <input type="submit" name="urgent process">
</form>
```

Comment: You can define a function on run it on submit, or you can watch the change of variables, when user is interacting, and change values depending on that

Comment: Why not use two switching forms instead?

Comment: It would make much more sense to put a `value` on the submit buttons and read that on the server side. That way you know what the price should be based on the `urgent`/`normal` value sent, and it's not so easy for someone to manipulate the value on the client side

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : You want to say that i should set the values in submit button and pass it to server side.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan - But i have some more hidden input field, that is common for both the processes.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you need to restructure how you send data within each request as that seems less than ideal for both repetition and security. If you need help with this I'd suggest starting a new question, possibly on CodeReview if the code is working.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Yes I Think So, I need to Change the Structure.

Comment: @OjibixCreatives, I will request you to try my updated answer.....

Comment: @Mamun : Thanks for the code, let me try this mate.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a radio button to select the state of the process and then infer the amount on the receiving end. That way users can't modify the value and you only have one button to submit the form while still having multiple options to choose from.

```html
<form name="home" action="#" method="post">
  Fee type:<br>
  <input type="radio" name="fee" value="normalfee">Normal<br>
  <input type="radio" name="fee" value="ugrentfee">Urgent<br>
  <input type="submit" name="Process">
</form>
```

Comment: But what if you want to have two choices (like two pictures to click on), and don't want to go that route?  Is there any other way?

Comment: Then you use the input type `checkbox`. https://jsfiddle.net/Lrfw4t8p/

Answer (score 0):

According to Form [`Controls`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.2)

> When a form is submitted for processing, some controls have their name paired with their current value and these pairs are submitted with the form.

You can check the attribute value on button click to remove the name attribute which will ultimately prevents the value from submitting:

```js
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
  $('#normalfee, #urgentfee').attr('name', 'fee');
  if($(this).attr('name') == 'Normal Process'){
    $('#urgentfee').removeAttr('name');
    $('#urgentfee').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  else{
    $('#normalfee').removeAttr('name');
    $('#normalfee').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  var passVal = $('form').serialize();
  alert(passVal);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="home" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="fee" id="normalfee" value="49">
  <input type="hidden" name="fee" id="urgentfee" value="99">
  <input type="submit" name="Normal Process">
  <input type="submit" name="urgent process">
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't affect the data that's sent when the form is submit. All you do is show the value in the console.

Comment: No problem. I'd also suggest disabling the field if this is the route you want to take.